# Calling WCF Service Operations in AJAX

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I have one asp.net application, in which i am using "Calling WCF Service Operations in AJAX" method. I finished my work without the service hosting in IIS. I got the correct solution. But now, i have another requirement in which i am using the WCF service which is hosted on local host iis. But in clicking the button i got one javascript error like object expected. I don't know why this happened?
My code is shown below.

```
<fieldset style="width: 804px" align="center">
    <legend>Consuming WCF Service using Client-Side AJAX</legend>
    <div align="left" style="text-align: center">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="http://localhost/WCFService/Service1.svc" />
                <%--~/Service1.svc--%>
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <input id="addNum1" type="text" size="3" />
        +
        <input id="addNum2" type="text" size="3" />
        =
        <input id="addAnswer" type="text" size="3" /><br />
        <input id="btnAddition" type="button" value="Do Addition" onclick="DoAddition()" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="subtractNum1" type="text" size="3" />
        -
        <input id="subtractNum2" type="text" size="3" />
        =
        <input id="subtractAnswer" type="text" size="3" /><br />
        <input id="btnSubtraction" type="button" value="Do Subtraction" onclick="DoSubtraction()" />
        <br />
        <br />
        </form>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function DoAddition() {
    Service1.Add(document.getElementById('addNum1').value, document.getElementById('addNum2').value, onAddSuccess);
}
function DoSubtraction() {
    Service1.Subtract(document.getElementById('subtractNum1').value, document.getElementById('subtractNum2').value, onSubtractSuccess);
}

function onAddSuccess(result) {
    document.getElementById('addAnswer').value = result;
}
function onSubtractSuccess(result) {
    document.getElementById('subtractAnswer').value = result;
}
```

the javascript error message is like this

[image: Picture]

Please help me for solving this issue.

Comment: is this working URL http://localhost/WCFService/Service1.svc ?  able to browse in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with java-script such as `Service1.Add..`. The name of generated js proxy would not be Service1 and hence the issue. The name of proxy object would be of form `[Namespace].[Contract Name]` where namespace of the service, as declared by the Namespace parameter of the ServiceContract attribute. If you haven't specified one the default is "`tempuri.org`". For example, if your service is defined as

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="Samples.Services")]
public class Service1
{
  [OperationContract]
  public void Add(...
```

Then in js, you need to use `Sample.Services.Service1.Add`